# for loop and while loop traversing on a directory working differenly in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have written a script in two different ways as below.

```
#! /bin/bash
chk=0
ls sid/. | while read dir   #<--second script just has a for loop instead
do
  if [ -e "sid/$dir/testfile" ]; then
     [ $chk -eq 0 ] && chk=1
     echo "$dir|testfile"
  fi
done
[ $chk -eq 0 ] && echo "No directory has testfile"
```

While loop gives me more control for the directories which have spaces between them. For loop just breaks them into two directories.

[image: Script comparison below]

In my case both of them work as expected only for the fact that the one with while loop prints the message "No directory has testfile" even if it finds a testfile in any of the directories.

Please help me understand how these 2 loops are working differently. Below are the outputs(findtestfile is script on the left screenshot above):

[image]

Comment: You should post your code in text, not image.

Comment: @ymonad Edited my question to accommodate the code in text

Comment: @WalterA Any way I can rewrite the script using the while loop itself ?

Comment: I see no reason to use screenshots in that question. If you want to show that two scripts are differ only in one line, you may add commented code `#for dir in ls sid/.*` to the **code snippet** instead with appropriate explanations. If you think everyone prefers reading that coloring screenshots than a plain code, then it is not true. Also, output could be perfectly represented as a plain text (you may format it as a code). Screenshots are useful for expose non-textual information, in other cases the text should be preferred.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding `ls` with a loop like

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do 
   echo "${dir}"
done < <(find sid -mindepth 1 -type d)
```

You can look for an alternative for the loop with

```
find sid -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name testfile -type f | 
   sed -r 's#sid/(.*)/(.*)#\1|\2#'
find sid -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name testfile -type f | 
   grep -q . || echo "No directory has testfile"
```